# Find out if a printer supports postscript

Tags: printer

I am trying to print to a Konica Minolta DiALTA di1611 printer from a linux desktop.  There are not linux drivers available.  I read that I can create the ppd file needed if the printer is a postscript printer.

So, is a 1611 a postscript printer?  How do I find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostScript is optional on the Di611. The easiest way to see if yours supports it is to send it a PS printjob. Be prepared to cancel the job as, if only PCL is supported, the job will print many pages of PostScript text.

Comment: How do I send a PS printjob?

Comment: Try sending this:  "<ESC>%–12345X@PJL <CR><LF>@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT <CR><LF>%!PS Adobe showpage <ctrl-D>". Send it without the quotes, and <ctrl-D> is the EOT character (hex 04), <CR> and <LF> are hex 0D and 0A. That will print a blank page if it supports PS, or print the text from %!PS if it does not.